# How to use cdn url with play framework and scala for image display?

Tags: scala, playframework, cdn

In my project i am uploading the images on cdn and getting a url path to that image. But it failed to display the image on a scala template using the given url as image src. I tried (in scala template):

```
<img src= @model.getImageURL() alt="Image placeholder">
```

Here i am saving the url in database as a model property and trying to retrieve it using the getter method.
Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the source contain the correct url? It looks to me like it should be
`<img src= "@model.getImageURL()" alt="Image placeholder">` unless your getImageURL() method wraps the string in quotes already

Comment: This was the issue. With inverted commas it's working fine. Thanks for the help @IanGabes

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to quote strings in templates, e.g. `src="@model.getImageURL"`